# Why is my AsyncMemoizer is not functioning properly in Flutter where I want to stop rebuilding my widget unnecessarily

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I am working on an App like Live TV which is basically a video based recommendation platform

What I noticed is that when I scroll in the "Home Page" of my app the stateful widget is been called again and again (because I am using Future builder)and because of this it is causing a huge consumption of data which a severe issue and I want it not to happen.

I used the concept of Memoization as per this article https://medium.com/saugo360/flutter-my-futurebuilder-keeps-firing-6e774830bc2 .The code throws no error. But after using it my home page is not loading.I can't understand as to why this is happenning?

Here is my future builder code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Build function called......................");

  body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            child: FutureBuilder(
                future: widgetLoadingFunctions(_selectedIndex),
                builder:
                    (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return widgetOptions(_selectedIndex);
                  } else
                    return //Asset.image('assets/loading.gif');
                        Image.asset('assets/loading.gif');
                })),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        fixedColor: Colors.amber,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
//          Icon(
//            FontAwesome.facebook_square,
//            color: Colors.amber,
//          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Home'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            icon: Icon(
              MaterialCommunityIcons.video_vintage,
            ),
            title: Text(
              'Movies',
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            icon: Icon(Icons.live_tv),
            title: Text(
              'Tv shows',
            ),
          ),

          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            icon: Icon(Icons.music_video),
            title: Text(
              'Music',
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            icon: Icon(Icons.radio),
            title: Text(
              'News',
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            icon: Icon(
              FontAwesome.heartbeat,
            ),
            title: Text(
              'LifeStyle',
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            icon: Icon(
              Ionicons.md_football,
            ),
            title: Text(
              'Sports',
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

The future function which is responsible for loading is as follows:

```
 Future<String> widgetLoadingFunctions(int idx) async {
    switch (idx) {
      case 0:
        return _memoizer.runOnce(() async {
          var x = await functionsToBeLoadedForHomePage();
          return x;
        });

      case 1:
        return await functionsToBeLoadedForMoviesPage();

      case 2:
        return await functionsToBeLoadedForTvSHowsPage();

      case 3:
        return await functionsToBeLoadedForMusicPage();

      case 4:
        return await functionsToBeLoadedForNewsPage();

      case 5:
        return await functionsToBeLoadedForLifeStylePage();

      case 6:
        return await functionsToBeLoadedForSportsPage();
    }
  }
```

I will implement the remaining functions in the same way afterwards using memoizer.

The declaration of memoizer is :

```
class _LiveTvHomePageState extends State<LiveTvHomePage> {

  final AsyncMemoizer _memoizer = AsyncMemoizer();
```

and the 1st function i.e.,functionsToBeLoadedForHomePage()is as follows:

```
Future<String> functionsToBeLoadedForHomePage() async {
    String url =
        "https://livetvapi.apyhi.com/api/v3/home?pageLocation=home&countries=IN&app_version=13&"
        "user_id=44edc2c905ae163f&package_id=livetv.movies.freemovies.watchtv.tvshows&os_platform=android";

    var res = await http
        .get(url, headers: {'Authorization': dartJsonWebTokenGenerator()});
    var _playListImgUrlsObjects = [];
    List<String> _thumbNailList = [];
    List<String> _titleNames = [];
    List<String> _subtitleNames = [];
    List<String> _noOfSongs = [];
    List<String> _playListVideoLinks = [];

    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      final _homePage = homePageFromJson(res.body);

      for (var homeBannerObject in _homePage.homeBanners) {
        for (var obj in homeBannerObject.thumbnail) {
          _homeBannerObjectthumbnailList.add(obj.toString());
        }

        _homeBannerObjectMovieIdList.add(homeBannerObject.movieId.substring(8));
      }

      for (var homeBannerObject in _homePage.movies) {
        for (var obj in homeBannerObject.thumbnail) {
          _popularMoviesthumbNail.add(obj.toString());
        }

        _popularMoviesMovieId.add(homeBannerObject.movieId.substring(8));
      }

      for (var homeBannerObject in _homePage.series) {
        for (var obj in homeBannerObject.thumbnail) {
          _seriesData.add(obj.toString());

          _seriesVideoLinks.add(homeBannerObject.posterLink.substring(23, 34) +
              "&list=" +
              homeBannerObject.seriesId.substring(8));
        }
      }

      for (var everyObj in _homePage.musicCategories) {
        for (var playlistsObj in everyObj.playlists) {
          _titleNames.add(playlistsObj.playlistName);
          _subtitleNames.add(playlistsObj.playlistDescription.substring(
                  0,
                  playlistsObj.playlistDescription.length <= 20
                      ? playlistsObj.playlistDescription.length
                      : 20) +
              "...");
          _noOfSongs.add(playlistsObj.playlistTotalTracks.toString());
          _playListVideoLinks.add(playlistsObj.playlistUrl);
          for (var playlistImagesObj in playlistsObj.playlistImages) {
            _thumbNailList.add(playlistImagesObj.url);
          }
        }

        _detailsOfMusicInHomePage[everyObj.categoryName] = [
          _thumbNailList,
          _titleNames,
          _subtitleNames,
          _noOfSongs,
          _playListVideoLinks
        ];

        _thumbNailList = [];
        _titleNames = [];
        _subtitleNames = [];
        _noOfSongs = [];
        _playListVideoLinks = [];
      }

      for (var playListObj in _homePage.musicPlaylists.playlists) {
        _musicCategories.add(playListObj.playlistName);
      }

      for (var publisherObj in _homePage.publishers) {
        _popularNewsChannelNames.add(publisherObj.fullName);
        _popularNewsChannelProfilePicUrl.add(publisherObj.profilePicUrl);
        _popularNewsChanneldesc.add(publisherObj.content.description);
      }

      for (var liveChannelObj in _homePage.liveChannels) {
        _liveNewsChannelProfilePicUrl.add(liveChannelObj.publisherProfilePic);
        _liveNewsChannelNames.add(liveChannelObj.publisherName);
      }

      for (var playlistsObj in _homePage.musicPlaylists.playlists) {
        _playListNames.add(playlistsObj.playlistName);
        _playListTotalTracks.add(playlistsObj.playlistTotalTracks.toString());
        _playListImgUrlsObjects.add(playlistsObj.playlistImages);
        _playListVideoUrls.add(playlistsObj.playlistUrl);
      }

      for (var listObj in _playListImgUrlsObjects) {
        for (var obj in listObj) {
          _playListImgUrls.add(obj.url.toString());
        }
      }

      _musicPlaylistThemeName = _homePage.musicPlaylists.categoryName;
      return "Successfully Exectued";
    } else
      return null;
  }
```

and the widget loading function is:

```
Widget widgetOptions(int idx) {
    Widget _selectedWidget = CircularProgressIndicator();
    switch (idx) {
      case 0:
        _selectedWidget = homePageForBottomNavigator();
        break;
      case 1:
        _selectedWidget = MoviesPageForBottomNavigator();
        break;
      case 2:
        _selectedWidget = TvSHowsPageOfBottomNavigator();
        break;
      case 3:
        _selectedWidget = MusicPageofBottomNavigator();

        break;
      case 4:
        _selectedWidget = NewsPageOfBottomNavigator();

        break;
      case 5:
        _selectedWidget = LifeStylePageOfBottomNavigator();
        break;
      case 6:
        _selectedWidget = SportsPageOfBottomNavigator();
    }
    return _selectedWidget;
  }
```

So basically in the future of future builder the corresponding functions of the necessary page is loaded and then it is displayed.

The HomePageWidget is this:

```
Widget homePageForBottomNavigator() {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildBody(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.35,
                _homeBannerObjectthumbnailList, _homeBannerObjectMovieIdList),

            HorizontalListView("Popular movies", _popularMoviesthumbNail,
                _popularMoviesMovieId),
            HorizontalListView(
                "Popular Tv shows", _seriesData, _seriesVideoLinks),
            //infinite list view to be implemented here
            HorizontalGridViewOfCardsofGradientColorWithtitle(
                1,
                "Music",
                _detailsOfMusicInHomePage.keys.toList(),
                _detailsOfMusicInHomePage),
            HorizontalListViewWithoutViewAll(
                "_musicPlaylistThemeName,",
                _playListImgUrls,
                _playListNames,
                _playListTotalTracks,
                _playListVideoUrls),
            HorizontalListViewWitCircularCards(
                "Popular News channels",
                _popularNewsChannelProfilePicUrl,
                _popularNewsChannelNames,
                _popularNewsChanneldesc,
                _detailsNewsPage),
            HorizontalListViewWithoutViewAllForLiveNewsChannels(
                "Live News Channels",
                _liveNewsChannelProfilePicUrl,
                _liveNewsChannelNames,
                _newsPageLiveNewsVideoUrls),

            //VerticalListView(["Latest News"],false),
          ],
        ), //end of 1st Widget
        Positioned(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.01,
            left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
            child: returnToTopButton()),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you are using `FutureBuilder` *incorrectly* and the medium article that you linked is providing an overly complex solution to a problem that stems from incorrect use. Don't trust everything you read, especially when they're not official docs.

The [docs of `FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) state:

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateConfig, or State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

You must obtain the `Future` *earlier* than `build`, like in `initState`. What you're doing now is obtaining the `Future` during `build`.

Obtain the `Future` during `initState`, store it in a variable, and pass that to the `FutureBuilder`.

```dart
Future storedFuture;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  storedFuture = widgetLoadingFunctions(_selectedIndex);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...

  body: SafeArea(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      controller: _scrollController,
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: storedFuture,
```

Comment: I have included the statement  print("Build function called......................"); under   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { ,gets printed again and again,though it seems more controlled now when I scroll down.

Comment: @ChethanVenkataramaiah You cannot control when build is called. Don't even try. However, what I show in my answer will stop repeated consumption of data. This is *not* a solution to stop build.

Comment: Sure,I would mark as accepted.Only thing is I can't understand why you shouldn't stop build and how exactly is this actually reducing data consumption.But I will mark it accepted

Comment: @ChethanVenkataramaiah Previously you had `widgetLoadingFunctions(_selectedIndex)` *in* build. This means every time the widget rebuilds, which cannot be completely controlled by us, it obtains a **new** `Future`. i.e. it's calling the function(and uses data) on very `build`. This is not recommended. Instead, when you obtain the `Future` in `initState`, widget rebuild will *not* obtain a new `Future` on every build. It will only obtain a Future **once**. You should think of build as being needed to make every frame on the screen. If you stop it, your app will not run smoothly. LMK if questions

Comment: But still there is an issue.Except for the first page the remaining pages are not getting the required data as initState is called only once.I tried called the widgetLoadingFunctions() inside setState of initState,but no use.Though you can combine all the functions and put in one function,it is going to take a long time to load.Any thoughts on how to overcome this issue?

Comment: @ChethanVenkataramaiah In the `onTap` of `BottomNavigationBar`, do `storedFuture = widgetLoadingFunctions(_selectedIndex)` in the `setState` immediately after `_selectedIndex = index;`

Comment: @Chethan Venkataramaiah -- these are too many questions for a single comment. :-) Basically, you use `FutureBuilder` when you expect it to run just once: load the data and display. When you expect that you would need repeated loads, you *don't* use it, you use `StreamBuilder` instead which is just made for this purpose (more or less the same, just that it can fire again and again, simply put).

Comment: @Chethan Venkataramaiah -- the second is a basic misunderstanding of how Flutter works, and it works rather differently from many other platforms, for sure. The name of `build()` is not really fortunate. Alwasy think of it as `displayThisFrame()` instead. It will be called repeatedly, yes, even up to the point of 60 or more times per second, that is, for each and every frame, if required. Every time something changes and needs to alter the display, `build()` will be called again and again -- that's just what it's for. So, basically, you only do things inside `build()` that you don't mind,

Comment: @Chethan Venkataramaiah -- or even expect to be called all the time. All the rest should be done outside `build()`, that's the main point.

Comment: @Gábor Your comment about using `StreamBuilder` for repeated loads is incorrect. `FutureBuilder` ***should*** be used for repeated loads by changing out the future provided to it. `StreamBuilder` should be used for *streams*, meaning data that changes over time. This does not mean it should be used if a user, for instance, pulled to refresh.

Comment: @Christopher Moore well, I beg to differ. There's absolutely nothing in a stream that forces you to provide values through it in a timed, regular manner. A stream is nothing but a vehicle that sends values, once, twice, many times, regularly or not, just like you wish. When the user pulls to refresh, you read a new value and send it across the stream. No problem with it at all, I do it all the time... :-) But I do accept it that a FutureBuilder might be used for this, too.

Comment: @Gábor While it's possible to do something like that, it's an anti-pattern. I never claimed that Stream data had to be timed & regular. If you wanted to do pulltorefresh with streams, you would need an **external** mechanism to trigger a new stream event, something that is not typical of a stream. Futures provide the necessary functionality in a way that is most native to the `FutureBuilder` and `Future` constructs that Flutter/Dart provide. I agree, using streams for this is possible to do, but it is not the ideal thing to do and should not be encouraged.

Comment: @Gábor In this situation presented by this question, providing a different future to the FutureBuilder provides the needed functionality in the best way possible. Your claim "When you expect that you would need repeated loads, you don't use [FutureBuilder]" is just wrong.

Comment: OK, we won't agree. :-) I don't normally use the expression anti-pattern because, most of the time, I consider this classification wrong, sometimes even utterly wrong. Using StreamBuilder in the scenario I mentioned even has some added benefits (eg. the possibility to provide UI feedback to the user that new data is on its way) but it's really not something we need to discuss here in comments. I already added to my previous comment that I did accept that FutureBuilder might also be used, so yes, I retracted my original statement in this regard...

Comment: ... but I will most definitely keep using StreamBuilder when I see it fit. And I see it fit in this case, very much so. Sorry...

Comment: @Gábor Again some slight mistakes in your comment. Since FutureBuilders are ***made*** for with reloadable futures in mind, it **is** possible to show UI feedback when new data is on the way. I recommend taking a look at the docs to refresh your memory of the capabilities and uses of these widgets.